# The way which you should hold them

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, noun-phrases, complements

The *Cambridge Grammar of the english Language*, page 224, reads

> Complements are most often NPs, and conversely NPs are usually
>   complements. Some NPs can occur with adjunct function, but they tend
>   to belong to very restricted semantic types, mainly time or manner.
>
> A distinctive property of such NPs is that they cannot be replaced by
>   personal pronouns:
>
> They saw her then/*it, You should hold them so/*it.
>
> **Similarly** there are no corresponding relatives with which: *the way that/∗which you should hold them*.

I do not understand the reason why *the way which you should hold them* is wrong, that is what relation "**similarly**" marks in the paragraph.

Comment: Please could you include your research?

Comment: You might consider that, as a learner, CGEL is a bit too advanced for you at the present time.

Comment: @marcellothearcane so far https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-way-which-you-should-hold-them.3625777/#post-18472052

Comment: See also Qs about *which* vs. *that* on this site.

Comment: That's not completely what I had in mind. I suggest you follow up on Kris's comment.

Comment: I don't understand what CGEL is getting at. Is it just that there should be a preposition in *the way **in** which you should hold them*?

Comment: They're saying that relative pronouns work like personal pronouns: both replace only complement NPs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Because *which* is a pronoun, it nearly always replaces an NP within the relative clause. Relative *that* doesn't seem to be a pronoun, but just a subordinator (although things are not absolutely clear cut), the same one we find in *I know that the earth is round*. It can occur with relative clauses where all kinds of different elements are missing, AdjP, AdvP, NP, VP etc etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers However! Adjunct NPs (read 'adverbial NPs') relating to time or manner etc cannot normally be replaced by pronouns. For this reason *which* relatives are not possible in relative clauses where the gap corresponds to an adjunct, even if that adjunct could easily be an NP.

Comment: @BillJ It's a good question though. I doubt many members here could answer it including a couple of the commenters here. [I'm not going to answer it though, because GJC never accepts any of the answers given them, or upvotes them either].

Comment: @Araucaria: I still don't get it. The asterisk in CGEL's example indicates 'invalid construction', and I'd certainly want that extra preposition in, say, [*You have an anti-virus software, you must learn the way **IN** which it works.*](http://equipro.com.br/best-antivirus-software-an-in-depth-anaylsis-on-what-works-and-what-doesnt/) Is that why they've included the asterisk?

Comment: ...AND - are they saying that [*The way **which** he used was this; (blah blah)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+way+which+he+used%22) is "syntactically invalid"? I certainly wouldn't include ***IN*** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reason that you can use *which* in your version is because it is replacing the complement of a preposition, not an adjunct. It *is* occurring *inside* an adjunct, but doesn't represent the adjunct itself. The adjunct is the preposition phrase *in which*. So, looking at it from that angle that is kind of why they have the asterisk, but really it's just to show that *which* can't be used to represent an adjunct, even if it's an NP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Re your *The way which he used* (there only seems to be one actual text cited in your link) is different, because there the word *which* represents the direct object of the verb *used*, not an adjunct. That's also why you can't add an *in* in that example. I don't think *to use a way* is very idiomatic in modern English (and may not have been even in the eighteenth century, by the looks of it!).

Answer (score 1):

Original:  the way which you should hold them

It's not "wrong" per se, but it is non-preferred.

"You should hold them" is a restrictive relative clause (essential, no commas).  "That" should be used for restrictive relative clauses.  "Which" should be used for nonrestrictive relative clauses.  A web search will tell you this.

=> the way THAT you should hold them 
(in this structure, "that" can be omitted without loss of meaning)

One reference:  https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/relative-clauses/